# How to mount USB Path in android?

Tags: android, usb, mount

I am using android tab `Ice Cream Sandwich` Version 4.0.3 to run my application. I am connect with external USB device and android Tab. How to i mount path of external USB device programmatically. Because i need to Browse files from USB device to my android tab.

So How to mount USB Path in android?

Comment: Its depends on your device manufacturer, Because android has only **Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()** concept.

Comment: Thanks. I agree it depends on the device. But i need solution.

Answer (score 1):

I am agree with [user370305](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11186083/how-to-mount-usb-path-in-android#comment14679674_11186083).

You can look in the Storage Settings. the mount paths seem to be there (for instance, /mnt/usbdisk_1.0/). Also, you might be able to just look in /mnt and see what is listed; I believe that that is what the various file manager apps do. There seem to be a number of mount points for USB drives; the ones that aren't yet mounted show up as empty, while the mounted ones let you browse into them (using a file explorer app like Astro).

Go through [this link](http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/Android-App-Development-for/What-s-the-USB-path-in-different-tablets/m-p/23590).

Comment: This will only work on devices where the vendor has extended Android with a **non-standard** ability to mount USB storage volumes.  **Stock Android does not support USB drives** at operating system level.  If a stock device has host mode, it is possible to talk to the drive at a low level using mass storage and file system code implemented in an application itself, but you are on your own with no help from the operating system's file system capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

[already given answer check Android detect usb mount point path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513537/android-detect-usb-mount-point-path/37162793#37162793)

```
  private String getAllStoragePath() {
    String finalPath = "";
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("mount");
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        String line;
        String[] pathArray = new String[4];
        int i = 0;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String mount = "";
            if (line.contains("secure"))
                continue;
            if (line.contains("asec"))
                continue;

            if (line.contains("fat")) {// TF card
                String columns[] = line.split(" ");
                if (columns.length > 1) {
                    mount = mount.concat(columns[1] + "/someFiles");

                    pathArray[i++] = mount;

                    // check directory inputStream exist or not
                    File dir = new File(mount);
                    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                        // do something here
                        finalPath = mount;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(String path:pathArray){
            if(path!=null){
                finalPath =finalPath + path +"\n";
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalPath;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, i use it as fallback, i first check if a file "proc/mounts" is existing and i read it, if not then i read it via this script. We should not relly on "fat" or "vfat" new devices sometimes has "fuse" as partition type, its big script detecting partition, but they starts with "/dev/" and may be vfat or fuse, and you may have duplicate paths to same partition, o beware of that.