# Android detect usb mount point path

Tags: android, usb, sd-card

I am working on a app that can connect to a USB SD card reader.
The problem is the USB path is not the same for all the phones. I know that in Samsung phones the USB path is "/storage/UsbDriveA/"

My question is how can I find the USB mount path for all phone devices?

thank you

Comment: I think there no direct API from android to find out the connected USB devices. May be [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16262830/how-to-find-the-path-of-usb-which-is-mounted-to-android) can help you.

Comment: hi thank you for the referral  I'm going to check it out

Comment: If the device is actually mounted in such a way as to be available to your app, it will be in your app process's version of /proc/mounts which can be read as a text file.  But don't assume that the device is literally mounted for you app (it may only be mounted for other process ancestries, or not actually mounted but rather interacted with using non-File code) and keep in mind that you will see a somewhat different /proc/mounts when exploring with adb than your app sees.

Answer (score 2):

```
    private String getAllStoragePath() {
    String finalPath = "";
    try {
        Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process process = runtime.exec("mount");
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        String line;
        String[] pathArray = new String[4];
        int i = 0;

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String mount = "";
            if (line.contains("secure"))
                continue;
            if (line.contains("asec"))
                continue;

            if (line.contains("fat")) {// TF card
                String columns[] = line.split(" ");
                if (columns.length > 1) {
                    mount = mount.concat(columns[1] + "/someFiles");

                    pathArray[i++] = mount;

                    // check directory inputStream exist or not
                    File dir = new File(mount);
                    if (dir.exists() && dir.isDirectory()) {
                        // do something here
                        finalPath = mount;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        for(String path:pathArray){
            if(path!=null){
                finalPath =finalPath + path +"\n";
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finalPath;
}
```